# Add div after every element with a particular class

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a way to automatically insert a div into my markup after every element with a particular class?

For example;

If I have the following markup

```
<div class="three-col"></div>

<div class="three-col"></div>

<div class="three-col last"></div>
```

Is there a way to add

```
<div class="after-last"></div>
```

Automatically after the "three-col last" div?

I'm creating a Wordpress theme and I've created some column shortcodes, but as the divs are floated left, if the last column has less content than the rest, any content added after it jumps up underneath it.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Try [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method.

```
$('.three-col.last').after('<div class="after-last"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If I was you I didn't use the last class, instead of that you can do something like that:

```
<div class="three-col"></div>

<div class="three-col"></div>

<div class="three-col"></div>

$('div.three-col:last').after('<div class="after-last"></div>');
```

Comment: Your welcome @DeanElliott. This solution is more dynamic... By the way, if you think that it was useful please mark it :P